# iOS UIPageViewController index not incrementing when page change

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement UIPageViewController and its working but the index is always cero. I implement :

```
-(UIViewController*)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSUInteger index=[self indexOfViewController:(contentViewController*)viewController];
     NSLog(@" index %d", index);
    if (index==NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}
```

but the index of the viewcontroller is never been updated. Any pointers of why?

Comment: What's the implementation of `indexOfViewController:`?

Comment: thank you the problem was on: -(NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(contentViewController *)viewController

Comment: Please explain what the solution was, just in case someone else is experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

on:

```
-(contentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

I was returning the index with value of cero. I fixed that everything work like just fine